# How do I detect the township of a location with Google Maps V3 API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps v3 API, how do I determine the township of a certain latitude/longitude location in the United States?

I could just store the boundaries of townships in an array of polygons and manually compute if the (latitude, longitude) falls into any of the polygons, but I was wondering if there was a more straightforward way to query for the township.

If I have to use the polygons method, where can I obtain polygons for various townships in the United States?

Comment: The [reverse geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) _may_ return the data you are looking for.

Comment: [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcodeD.html) (not sure what field you would want).